# How to use a selector to tab through elements using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, tabbing

I am trying to navigate a series of elements with the arrow keys, which I can successfully do like so:

Javascript:

```
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode==39) {
    $('div').next(this).focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode==37) {
    $('div').prev(this).focus();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div tabindex='0'>
a
</div>
<div tabindex='0'>
b
</div>
<div tabindex='0'>
c
</div>
```

But if I add an element in between two `divs`, like so:

```
<div tabindex='0'>
a
</div>
<span tabindex='0'>
wat
</span>
<div tabindex='0'>
b
</div>
<div tabindex='0'>
c
</div>
```

The arrow keys do not skip the `span` and remain stuck on the second and third `divs`. Please see my demo for my implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/obliviga/a0uz64xw/5/

I basically want the focus with the arrow keys only to remain on a selector of my choice, so that the `span` is skipped. I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)** and **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** along with **[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** pseudo class selector since **[`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** and **[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** only selects immediate adjacent sibling. Where **[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** is helping to get the nearest one from the collection.

```
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode==39) {
    $(this).nextAll('div:first').focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode==37) {
    $(this).prev('div:first').focus();
  }
});
```

```js
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $(this).nextAll('div:first').focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $(this).prevAll('div:first').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex='0'>
  a
</div>
<span tabindex="0">
wat
</span>
<div tabindex='0'>
  b
</div>
<div tabindex='0'>
  c
</div>
```